# Left over indicator in activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager

I want to implement left over  pages to be filled in all the activities. I have 10 activities and I want to show user the left screens to be filled just like indicator in view pager android. I tried searching, all I am getting is indicators for ViewPager but nothing for activities. [image]

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Activities? The recommended way to make this kind of behavior is using a single Activity with a ViewPager that contains 10 Fragments.

Comment: Why do you want to use activities instead of fragments?  If you still want to execute the same then you need to create custom layout need to pass position on click of right or left arrow.

Comment: @RafiqAhmad there won't be arrows but the buttons in each activities.

Comment: @Mehdi Use fragments lot easier approach.